# Enabling Company CAPF backend with timer in Major Mode

Tags: major-mode, completion, company-mode, timers

I've be working on a new major mode for a DSL. I'm planning to use the CAPF backend for company mode and would like to provide the integration. The completion at point functions produce the correct options and when I explicitly call `company-complete` from the minibuffer, the correct completions come up. I'd like to have the completion kick in after a timer interval as I've seen in other modes. Company provides a setting for deciding the duration of the timer, so I don't think I should have to initialize one myself.

I'm new to company mode and don't know if this is a problem in my mode or in my configuration.  How do I get this to work?

Comment: Have you activated `company-mode` for that buffer and added your backend to `company-backends`?

Comment: It's the CAPF backend which is already in the list. Company mode is on.